# VAO renders fine on macOS, but INVALID_OPERATION on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, qt, opengl

I have an application that uses OpenGL within a Qt Widgets application. I used to develop it on macOS where everything worked fine, before switching over to Linux. Now when I call `glBindVertexArray(mesh->getVao());`, OpenGL spits out INVALID_OPERATION.

Using AMD's CodeXL, I determined that `mesh->getVao()` retuened `2`. I also used it to get a list of all OpenGL calls. Upon examining it, it seems to generate a VAO with the ID of 2, and there is no `glDeleteVertexArrays` within the call list. I even commented out the code that would delete the vertex array.

[image: The call list, when it generates the VAO]

The OpenGL docs state that the only reason `glBindVertexArray` could fail is if it is is not given zero, or a generated VAO.

Are there any other possible reasons why `glBindVertexArray` could spit out INVALID_OPERATION, despite the VAO existing, and why it could work on macOS but not on Linux?

---

A few code samples, if it helps

Mesh rendering

```cpp
void renderMesh(const Resource::ResourceMesh *mesh) {
    //Set up textures
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mesh->getTextures().size(); i++) {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
        mesh->getTextures().at(i)->getTexture()->bind();
    }
    static const int texIDs[32] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31};
    glUniform1iv(shaderTexID, MAX_SHADER_TEXTURES, texIDs);

    //Draw the mesh
    glBindVertexArray(mesh->getVao());
    qDebug() << "mesh == nullptr:" << (mesh == nullptr);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, mesh->getIndices().size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

VAO generation

```cpp
//In ResourceMesh.hpp

protected:
    QVector<Model::Vertex> vertices;
    QVector<unsigned int> indices;
    QVector<Resource::ResourceTexture*> textures;

    GLuint vao;
    GLuint vbo;
    GLuint ebo;

//In ResourceMesh.cpp

void ResourceMesh::generateGlBuffers() {
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Model::Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Vertex positions
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLManager::VertexAttribs::VERTEX_POSITION);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLManager::VertexAttribs::VERTEX_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Model::Vertex), (void*) offsetof(Model::Vertex, position));

    //Vertex normals
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLManager::VertexAttribs::VERTEX_NORMAL);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLManager::VertexAttribs::VERTEX_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Model::Vertex), (void*) offsetof(Model::Vertex, normal));

    //Vertex texture coordinates
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLManager::VertexAttribs::VERTEX_TEX_COORD);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLManager::VertexAttribs::VERTEX_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Model::Vertex), (void*) offsetof(Model::Vertex, texCoord));

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And if it helps, here's a screenshot of CodeXL, breaking at `glBindVertexArray`

[image: AMD CodeXL]

Comment: Please check if your Linux machine has [`GL_ARB_vertex_array_object`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_vertex_array_object.txt) extension. Chances are that it does not, hence the problem.

Comment: @hidefromkgb The extension is listed under Nvidia X Server Settings.

Comment: The GL_INVALID_OPERATION error may be triggered by a previous gl command. When something works in a OS but not in other, I suspect about driver capabilities. In this case `glActiveTexture` max and `glUniform1iv` max uniform size.

Comment: @Ripi2 CodeXL forces a debug context and lets me pinpoint which call triggers GL_INVALID_OPERATION. Also I just commented that out and still get the same issue.

Comment: A shot in the dark: call `glBindVertexArray`  before `glActiveTexture` and `glUniform1iv`

Comment: @Ripi2 Just tried binding `0`, and `mesh->getVao()` before `glActiveTexture` and `glUniform1iv`. Still nope.

Comment: The error can be triggered at `glBindVertexArray` but **due to** a previous command. Try without glActiveTexture and/or glUniform1iv.

Comment: @Ripi2 As I mentioned, I tried commenting that out, and still get the same issue.

Comment: You have two contexts. Do you set as current the context whose VAO applies?

Comment: @Ripi2 Ah shoot. I feel like an idiot now. The VAO was being created on the wrong context. I guess macOS Qt happens to use the same context for everything, where as the Linux implementation seperates them.

Comment: @CraftedCart: That should be an answer, not part of the question.

Comment: It's okay to post an answer to your own question. Please don't put the answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the comments - Turns out the VAO was being created on the wrong context. I guess the macOS implementation of Qt shares a context for everything, whereas on Linux, they're seperated.